# Installing SSMS 2014 giving error of DLL required

Tags: sql, installation, ssms-2014

I'm installing SSMS 2014 but while installing I'm getting below error:-

> "There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required
>   for this installation to complete could not be run. Contact your
>   support personnel or package vendor."

Can anyone tell me what is the problem?

Here is the error log:

```
Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Management Tools - Complete
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Native Client Access Component
  Component error code:          1723
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20150528_153228\sqlncli_Cpu64_1.log
  Error description:             There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this installation to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.2000.8&EvtType=sqlncli.msi%40RollbackCleanup%401723

  Feature:                       Client Tools Connectivity
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Common Files
  Component error code:          2331
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20150528_153228\sql_common_core_Cpu64_1.log
  Error description:             The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2331.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.2000.8&EvtType=sql_common_core.msi%40Do_LogInstallStart_64%402331

  Feature:                       Client Tools SDK
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Native Client Access Component
  Component error code:          1723
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20150528_153228\sqlncli_Cpu64_1.log
  Error description:             There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this installation to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.2000.8&EvtType=sqlncli.msi%40RollbackCleanup%401723

  Feature:                       Client Tools Backwards Compatibility
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Common Files
  Component error code:          2331
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20150528_153228\sql_common_core_Cpu64_1.log
  Error description:             The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2331.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.2000.8&EvtType=sql_common_core.msi%40Do_LogInstallStart_64%402331

  Feature:                       Management Tools - Basic
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Native Client Access Component
  Component error code:          1723
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20150528_153228\sqlncli_Cpu64_1.log
  Error description:             There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this installation to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.2000.8&EvtType=sqlncli.msi%40RollbackCleanup%401723

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Native Client Access Component
  Component error code:          1723
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20150528_153228\sqlncli_Cpu64_1.log
  Error description:             There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this installation to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.2000.8&EvtType=sqlncli.msi%40RollbackCleanup%401723

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity SDK
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Native Client Access Component
  Component error code:          1723
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20150528_153228\sqlncli_Cpu64_1.log
  Error description:             There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this installation to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.2000.8&EvtType=sqlncli.msi%40RollbackCleanup%401723
```

Comment: can you add logs so we can see specifically what is happening? We can't tell anything from that one error message.

Comment: can you retrieve the log from C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20150528_153228\sqlncli_Cpu64_1.log - there will be a line in there telling you which dll is missing or had problems with.  Alternatively upload log on filesharing site and share link

Comment: http://jmp.sh/58QpfVp  This is the link of log file

Comment: try this solution I found on the windows forums:
"go into c:\users\"username"\AppData\Local\  then right click on "temp" and choose "properies". Choose "security" --> edit --> add, and add the username you are using, and give yourself all rights."

If it works I'll add as answer

Comment: I tried this still no luck.

Comment: Is your version of Windows Installer up to date? Also might be worth trying this - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/mats/program_install_and_uninstall

Comment: Windows ® Installer. V 5.0.7601.17514 , This is the version of Installer.

Comment: also the link you mentioned. While running it, it is throwing error "We're sorry, but the program encountered an error trying to contact server. Please Try again later. [code 8004FE33]"

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by NOT putting in a DEFAULT target server URL when prompted.   It is an optional field, so leave it blank, click next, and the installation completes without issue.   You can add that link later once the application installs.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it as administrator. Right click on setup.exe file and click run as administrator.